# How to read multiple Json files under sub directories using Scala

Tags: json, scala, hadoop

I am looking a code snippet to find the best practice to read multiple nested JSON files under sub directories in hadoop using scala .

If we can write into one single file in some other directory in hadoop the above JSON files , that would be even better .

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
PG

Comment: :  are you using Spark with Scala API or how you are using Scala in Hadoop?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using spark with scala API .

Comment: You can use `sqlContext.read.json("json file path")` to read json file, it returns an `DataFrame`. But you said nested directories, is the json files are having different schemas?

Comment: Thanks Shankar . Files will be of similar schemas , and I guess it worked to read the files. Now next step is can I write all the files into one single json file may be in 1-2 steps to be performance efficient.

Comment: Take a look here. I think the top answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203217/how-to-load-directory-of-json-files-into-apache-spark-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlContext.read.json("input file path")` to read json file, it returns an DataFrame.

Once you got the DataFrame, just use df.write.json("output file path") to write the DF as json file.

**Code example: if you use Spark 2.0**

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL JSON example")
      .getOrCreate()

      val df = spark.read.json("input/file/path")

      df.write.json("output/file/path")
```