# Apache Spark Processing Capabilites & Eligibility

Tags: json, mongodb, python-3.x, apache-spark

I am new at Apache Spark and wonder whether it is eligible for my specific scenario or not. In my case, I am crawling small datasets (as JSON files to MongoDB). Those files are actually related with the same entity but it is possible for them to have different structures (a specific JSON in the same collection may include more or less key/value pairs compared the other ones). What I am trying is to run Machine Learning (classification / regression) algorithms on those data files and derive info from them.

When you consider the case do you think Spark is eligible to speed things up by processing in parallel in a cluster environment? Or do you thing I should converge to some other alternatives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel processing is a way to go for the big data world of today. And considering your case, `Spark` is definitely a good choice. `Spark` is `in-memory computation tool` which operates with `driver-executor scheme`. Memory is most important factor to consider for choosing `spark`. you can check out [Apache-spark](https://spark.apache.org/)

Since your project is related to machine learning, `spark` has a lot of libraries for machine learning [mllib-guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-guide.html)

[MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector) is supported too. you can check out [databricks use case](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/20/using-mongodb-with-spark.html)

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apache Spark supports these kinds of use cases. You can directly read from your JSON files, if you want. MongoDB as a data source is also supported. But, most importantly why you should use Spark is because it supports Machine Learning Algorithms directly on the datasets and you get parallel processing, fault tolerance, lazy loading and a lot more!

Referencing directly from their Machine Learning Page -

Its goal is to make practical machine learning scalable and easy. At a high level, it provides tools such as:

- ML Algorithms: common learning algorithms such as classification, regression, clustering, and collaborative filtering
- Featurization: feature extraction, transformation, dimensionality reduction, and selection
- Pipelines: tools for constructing, evaluating, and tuning ML Pipelines
- Persistence: saving and load algorithms, models, and Pipelines
- Utilities: linear algebra, statistics, data handling, etc.

Check out their page on Machine Learning for more details - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html

MongoDB as a data source - https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/20/using-mongodb-with-spark.html
Loading JSON files from a folder directly - [How to load directory of JSON files into Apache Spark in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203217/how-to-load-directory-of-json-files-into-apache-spark-in-python)

Moreover, it has API's in Python, R, Scala, and Java! Choose whatever you are comfortable in.